# Wrong SDL origin axis in 1080x1920 resolution

Tags: c++, sdl, xrandr

I am facing an issue with the SDL library and different resolution than 1920x1080.

I want to copy display an **image of dimension 1080x608** at the center of a **screen of resolution 1080x1920** (portrait).

**I have only one plugged monitor screen.**

I used the following command to switch screen from **1920x1080** to **1080x1920** :

```
xrandr --output DP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --rotate left --primary
```

I am using the following code to initialize the SDL renderer :

```
/**
 * initialize everything so we are ready to display
 */
int SdlHandler::initialize(
    unsigned int positionX,
    unsigned int positionY,
    unsigned int width,
    unsigned int height,
    bool showWindow,
    std::string name) {
    // Initialize SDL
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
            std::cerr << "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;

            return -1;
    }

    // Size if the window
    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;
    this->positionX = positionX;
    this->positionY = positionY;

    // Create the SDL window
    // 0 and 0 are the position in X and Y
    unsigned int flags = SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS;

    if (showWindow) {
            flags |= SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN;
    } else {
            flags |= SDL_WINDOW_HIDDEN;
    }

    this->window = SDL_CreateWindow(name.c_str(), this->positionX, this->positionY, this->width, this->height, flags);

    // If there had been a problem, leave
    if (!this->window) {
            return -1;
    }

    // Create a new renderer
    this->renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(this->window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);

    // If there is an error creating it, just leave
    if (!this->renderer) {
            return -1;
    }

    // Setup the best for the SDL render quality
    SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "2");

    return 0;
}
```

Then, i call the `SDL_RenderCopy` function to display the image. I pass it the created `renderer` created with the`SDL_CreateRenderer` on the above code :

```
// Create a window at 0,0 of dimension 1080x1920
this->initialize(0, 0, 1080, 1920, true, SDL_BASE_DISPLAY_WINDOW);

// Create the SDL Rectangle that will contain the image, at the center of the window
SDL_Rect *howToDraw = new SDL_Rect();
howToDraw->x = this->positionX + floor((this->width - this->imageWidth) / 2);
howToDraw->y = this->positionY + floor((this->height - this->imageHeight) / 2);
howToDraw->w = this->imageWidth;
howToDraw->h = this->imageHeight;

SDL_RenderCopy(this->renderer, this->texture, NULL, howToDraw);
```

But the axis seems to be at the wrong position, igot the following result :
[image]

### EDIT AND SOLUTION

This was a bug related to Compton, the window manager, everything is working good without Compton ...

Comment: What result did you *expect*?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i expected to have the origin 0,0 on top - left corner of the monitor, but actually it is on the top - left corner of a monitor that does not exist, being above. I made an arrow on the image "I want the origin here"

Answer (score 2):

Since you are rotating your display using `xrandr`, we can consider this is a post processing step that will rotate everything after each framebuffer is rendered.

Because this post processing step takes a 1920x1080 image resolution as input, you should use the SDL at this resolution.

What if you change your code for:

```
// Create a window at 0,0 of dimension 1920x1080
this->initialize(0, 0, 1920, 1080, true, SDL_BASE_DISPLAY_WINDOW);
```

EDIT: I also understand that you want your image to start at the center of the window, but your are placing the middle of the image at the center of the window.

You should also try the following:

```
howToDraw->x = this->positionX + this->imageWidth / 2;
```

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstanding, the xrandr command is computed at first, before running program. When the program starts running, the screen is already **1080x1920**. The image resolution is **1080x608**

Comment: @Alrick It doesn't matter *when* the command runs, the rotation is done after everything is drawn on a 1920x1080 display.

Comment: Yes, but the rotation will still happen after drawing the frame before displaying on the physical screen.